# How to call MessageBox like Popup from Scheduler task agent Windows Phone 7.x

Tags: windows-phone-7

My Web Service returns xml.In OnInvoke method I have xml data  it contains time and some text that are to be shown at given times on popup.

Answer (score 2):

As per Unsupported APIs of Background Agents, you can not use MessageBox from Schedule Agent.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

The best solution to display a message from Schedule Agent is Toast Notification.

Answer (score 1):

Normal message box access is as follows

```
MessageBox.Show("Enter your  data here");
```

But i am not sure about the message box access while the app is in ideal.

But you can show a Toast message, while the app is in ideal also.

here the sample code to show a Toast message

```
 Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellToast toast = new Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellToast();
            toast.Content = "mydata";
            toast.Title = "title";
            toast.NavigationUri = new Uri("/LocationDealsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            toast.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a message box according to your own design using user control. Then make an object of that control on your class where you want to use it. Make a popoup object and set control object as the child of pop up object.

```
UserControlName objectname = new UserControlName ();

PopUP popup = new PopUP();
popup.Child = objectname ;
popup.IsOpen = true;
```

I think it will help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.child(v=vs.95).aspx

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-get-user-input-from-a-popup-in-windows-phone